# Laravel/Slick: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, slick.js

I'm trying to place some testimonials on my Laravel website with Slick. I've followed this instruction to create the testimonials: https://codepen.io/mark_sottek/pen/mJdByp

When adding all the Scripts as said, I always get the error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function".

I've already tried several solutions I found here, but none of them did work for me.

My Code:

```
<section class="quotes">
    <div class="bubble">
        <blockquote>I refuse to accept the view that mankind is so tragically bound to the starless midnight of racism and war that the bright daybreak of peace and brotherhood can never become a reality... I believe that unarmed truth and unconditional love will have the final word.</blockquote>
        <div></div>
        <cite> Martin Luther King, Jr.</cite>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble">
        <blockquote> Peace is not a relationship of nations. It is a condition of mind brought about by a serenity of soul. Peace is not merely the absence of war. It is also a state of mind. Lasting peace can come only to peaceful people.</blockquote>
        <div></div>
        <cite> Jawaharlal Nehru</cite>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble">
        <blockquote> Forgiveness is not always easy. At times, it feels more painful than the wound we suffered, to forgive the one that inflicted it. And yet, there is no peace without forgiveness.</blockquote>
        <div></div>
        <cite> Marianne Williamson</cite>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble">
        <blockquote>Of all our dreams today there is none more important - or so hard to realise - than that of peace in the world. May we never lose our faith in it or our resolve to do everything that can be done to convert it one day into reality. </blockquote>
        <div></div>
        <cite> Lester B. Pearson</cite>
    </div>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('slick/slick.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.quotes').slick({
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 6000,
            speed: 800,
            slidesToShow: 2,
            adaptiveHeight: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thank you for any help.

Update:
Whole Error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):19)
    at j (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Seems like `slick.min.js` is not being loaded at all. Have you checked your browser's dev tools network tab?

Comment: `slick.min.js` is loaded correctly after the jquery files according to my browser's dev tools. Seems as everything is loaded correctly.

Comment: Then it's a case of `slick.min.js` being loaded after document is ready. Move all the script tags to the `<head>` of your document.

Comment: I still receive the same error when I place all script tags in the `<head>`. Maybe it helps when I give the whole error message? I've updated the post with the whole error message

Answer (score 0):

Update your jquery-1.11.0.min.js file to a newer version of jquery. This will resolve the error.